# iOS Push Notification connection.write error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification, rubygems, apple-push-notifications

Whenever I try sending a push notification from my Rails server using the gem Houston, it gives me an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/api/v1/messages_controller.rb:77:in `create'
```

It points on the line: connection.write(notification.message)
notification.message is a string value.

I don't know as to what is causing this since it occurs on the notification sending code itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured it out. A very stupid error but what I passed was wrong and it came out as nil. Should have passed in *connection.write(**msg_notification**.message)* instead of *connection.write(**notification**.message)*.